# Filter wordpress comments by approved

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, wordpress-theming

I use this to get wordpress comments for my custom themes:

```
get_comments( array('status' => 'aprove','order' => 'ASC', 'post_id' => $newpost->ID) );
```

Everything works besides the fact that comments that are awaiting moderation are not filtered.
Following the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment `'status' => 'approve'` should filter those out but that doesn't seem to happen.

Didn't I use it the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `approve` with two Ps!

```
get_comments( array('status' => 'approve','order' => 'ASC', 'post_id' => $newpost->ID) );
```

Here's [the docs page for get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) (you linked to `get_comment` singular.)

Comment: it happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me.** You can use the following code to show your approved comments in paragraph.

```
<?php foreach (get_comments(array('status' => 'approve','order' => 'ASC', 'post_id' => $newpost->ID)) as $comment): ?>
<div class="comment-show"><h4><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said: </h4> <p>"<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>"</p></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

i have used in following site to show comments
http://rumpa07cse.com/how-to-index-your-website-and-blog-very-quick/